# React (typescript) property data shows as undefined when specifying by attribute/prop name instead of generic "props"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, maps

First would like to point out that Typescript is completely new to me and still working on react.

So what I'm attempting to do is to map the list of names from the docs I queried from Firestore to display on the web. The issue being first that I get the error that there is an uncaught promise on my function to query the docs (specifically in the where() function) which I've checked over many times and cannot find the issue to.

The 2nd and most puzzling issue is I can console.log just fine the props in the child  component but if I specify the props.title it comes back as undefined even though I can clearly see it shows fine the other way.

RoomListContainer file:

```js
const RoomListContainer = (props: Props) => {
    const styles: Styles = {
        container:
            'bg-purple-200 rounded-2xl ml-4 overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden scrollbar scrollbar-thumb-purple-500 scrollbar-track-purple-300 hover:scrollbar-thumb-purple-400 scrollbar-thin scrollbar-thumb-rounded-full scrollbar-track-rounded-full',
    };

    const [userRooms, setUserRooms] = useState<any>([]);
    const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    const { currentUser } = useContext(UserContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            GetRooms();
        };
    }, [, update]);

    const refreshRooms = () => {
        setUpdate((prevState) => !prevState);
    };

    const GetRooms = async () => {
        const roomsRef = collection(db, 'Rooms');
        const userRoomsQuery = query(
            roomsRef,
            where('users', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid) // <- Uncaught promise error saying there is undefined data even tho console logging gives me all data just fine
        );
        // console.log(userRoomsQuery);

        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(userRoomsQuery);
        !querySnapshot
            ? console.log('No Data')
            : setUserRooms(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc: any) => doc.id));

        setTimeout(() => setIsLoading(false), 700);
    };

    // console.log(userRooms);
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            {isLoading ? (
                <p>Loading Rooms...</p>
            ) : (
                userRooms.map((room: any) => (
                    <RoomContainer
                        key={Math.random() * 9}
                        data-title={room}
                    />
                ))
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Child component RoomContainer file:

```js
const RoomContainer = (props: Props) => {
    const styles: Styles = {
        selectedRoomBG: 'bg-purple-100 w-[100%] flex flex-col transition',
        unselectedRoomBG:
            'bg-purple-200 w-[90%] rounded-r-full flex flex-col mx-auto',
        topPad: 'bg-purple-200 h-[10px] rounded-br-full transition',
        roomTitle: 'ml-2 w-full text-left hover:text-purple-600',
        bottomPad:
            'bg-purple-200 h-[10px] rounded-tr-full transition border-t-2 border-purple-400',
        bottomPadSelected:
            'bg-purple-200 h-[10px] rounded-tr-full border-t-[1px] border-purple-400 transition',
    };

    const [selectedRoom, setSelectedRoom] = useState(false);
    const [roomTitle, setRoomTitle] = useState();

    const selectRoom = () => {
        setSelectedRoom((prevState) => !prevState);
    };

    // const borderDisplay = selectedRoom ? {styles.bottomPadSelected} : {styles.bottomPad};

    const roomDisplay = (
        <div>
            <div className={styles.topPad} />
            <button className={styles.roomTitle}></button>
            <div className={styles.bottomPad} />
        </div>
    );

    console.log(props.title); // <- Comes up undefined
  console.log(props.data-title); // <- Comes up in IDE as not recognized
    console.log(props); // <- Works

    return (
        <div
            className={
                selectedRoom
                    ? styles.selectedRoomBG
                    : styles.unselectedRoomBG
            }
            onClick={selectRoom}
        >
            {roomDisplay}
        </div>
    );
};

export default RoomContainer;
```

Any ideas or guidance on what's going on would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not passing the title prop from parent to the child component. Hence, it is undefined

Comment: Also just want to point out I would have used just 'title' rather than 'data-title' for my custom attribute except that Typescript doesn't like custom attributes so to conform to its rules I added the "data-' part to it for it accept.

If anyone can give guidance on how to use just the 'title' as a custom attribute on my <RoomContainer/> I'd greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

You pass the prop "data-title" from parent to child component, there is no "title" that's why it is undefined. Here is [everything you need to know about props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)
Also, you type your userRooms as "any", consider actually typing it, as this is the main purpose of typescript

Comment: I put into the code how I already tried with data-title and all variations. None of them works. I don't have my  userRooms type to make it easier for me as I figur eout this error and then once I do I'll have it Typed correctly when I figure out the type lol eventuallym thanks for you input tho

Comment: what do you see in console.log(props); ?

Comment: What I use to see was the normal data of the docs pulled. @Marat

**So I somehow managed to fix the issue tho and to anyone wondering who might have a similar issue, restarted my pc and re-running the local server seems to have fixed my issue. Looks like it was just an IDE glitch or something similar!**

Don't forget to restart your IDE or pc! That might fix the issue for you if everything in your code looks good!